# AngularJS directive: put a call function in an attribute, without including another attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

### What I'm after

I would like to create a `ngLoad` directive for images on my webpage. This is my preferred markup:

```
<img ng-src="{{ src }}" ng-load="onLoad()">
```

### What I have

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerEich/Fx5th/2/)**

Right now, I have a `imgLoad` directive with `ngLoad` specified in the `scope`, like so:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('imgLoad', [function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            loadHandler: '&ngLoad'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.on('load', scope.loadHandler);
        }
    };
}]);
```

The resulting markup is:

```
<img ng-src="{{ src }}" img-load ng-load="onLoad()">
```

**Edit:** I previously assumed that the name of the directive (i.e. `imgLoad`) needed to be different from the name of my attribute (i.e. `ngLoad`). This is not the case. **The solution is to name my directive `ngLoad`.**

### What needs to change

I want to get rid of the `imgLoad` attribute. I want `ngLoad` to work regardless of any other attributes.

### What I've already seen

My implementation is based on:

- [angularjs directive call function specified in attribute and pass an argument to it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17556703/angularjs-directive-call-function-specified-in-attribute-and-pass-an-argument-to)
- [AngularJS - Image "onload" event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17547917/angularjs-image-onload-event)
- AngularJS: [introduction to directives](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive) and [$compile documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile)

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/7NyTN/ doesnt this work? why 2 directives?

Comment: @smk I think you answered my question. I had assumed the name of the directive needed to be different from the scope property.

Comment: So, this question doesn't make sense, given the OP assumptions. Might as well remove it.

Comment: I still think the question is a good reference, especially for those just starting to write directives (like me).

Comment: I updated my original post to explain my assumptions. I would like @smk to put his comment into an answer. If that doesn't happen in a few days, I'll probably answer my own question, crediting him for his solution

Answer (score 21, accepted):

## Simple Solution Using Isolate Scope

*Thanks to [@smk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/578116/smk) for this answer*

Give the directive and the scope property the same name.

```
app.directive('imgLoad', function() { // 'imgLoad'
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            loadHandler: '&imgLoad' // 'imgLoad'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr) {
            element.on('load', scope.loadHandler);
        }
    };
});
```

HTML:

```
<img img-load="onLoad()">
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerEich/gHqTK/2/)** • [AngularJS Guide to Isolate Scopes](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_demo_isolating-the-scope-of-a-directive)

While this solution is practical for most situations, it prevents you from using another directive with an isolate scope on the same element. Which brings us to…

## More Control Using $parse

Use `$parse` to process the attributes yourself. The effect will be the same, and there won't be any conflicts with isolate scopes.

```
app.directive('imgLoad', ['$parse', function($parse) { // Inject $parse
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {
            var loadHandler = $parse(attr.imgLoad); /* Parse value of
                                                       'imgLoad' attribute */
            element.on('load', function() {
                loadHandler(scope); /* Run the function returned by $parse.
                                       It needs the scope object
                                       to operate properly. */
            });
        }
    };
}]);
```

HTML (looks the same as before):

```
<img img-load="onLoad()">
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TylerEich/5Gng7/1/)** • [AngularJS $parse Documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$parse)

*Side Note: I didn't use ngLoad because [Angular advises against it](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#creating-custom-directives_creating-directives)*

Comment: I am trying your code, but the loadhandler never gets called.. Is `on` load event happens ?