# how to access object property via isolate scope without two-way binding?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to pass a product's id to a directive like so:

```
<widget product-id="product.id"></widget>
```

I prefer not to use curly braces:

```
<widget product-id="{{product.id}}"></widget>
```

because it's more verbose, and I want to match the style of ng-model usage.

I want to use isolate scope so that I can't accidentally modify product.id inside the widget.

If I use:

```
scope {
  productId: '@'
}
```

Then in my directive template: `{{productId}}` gives me the string `"product.id"`

If I use:

```
scope {
  productId: '&'
}
```

I see no output in my directive template `{{productId}}`, and as I understand it `&` is for binding functions not properties.

If I use:

```
scope {
  productId: '='
}
```

I get the exact value that I want (a number), but isn't this two-way binding and vulnerable to changing the product.id in the widget?

Comment: What are you doing with the ID? You should pass in the whole model if you need it... You shouldn't need to pass in a ID somewhere.

Comment: If you are afraid to change it, then just remove it from the scope after you've used it or stored in a variable.

Comment: I'm grabbing images for the product.  I don't think I require the whole model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to avoid the double curlys you can use [`$parse`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24parse) to process the [Angular expression](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression) yourself:

> Expressions are JavaScript-like code snippets that are usually placed
>   in bindings such as {{ expression }}. Expressions are processed by the
>   $parse service.

To use `$parse` in your directive you need to provide a scope (context) to parse against.  Since you're using an isolated scope the value of `product.id` will be on the directive's parent's scope- so we'll use `scope.$parent`.

Here's an example:

```
 myApp.directive('widget', function ($parse) {
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            productId: '@'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attr) {          
               nvalue = $parse(scope.productId)(scope.$parent);
               console.log("parse result",nvalue);
        }         
    };
});
```

[demo fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K47xR/2/)

Comment: thank you for the clear explanation of using $parse.  I didn't understand the documentation of passing scope in.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid there is no binding that fits your need, you can try this:

```
link:function(scope, element, attr){
          scope.productId = scope.$parent.$eval(attr.productid);
}
```

But this approach is not recommended

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/a6jxVIiqIBEiGUH3iYXz?p=catalogue)

The recommended approach is using `@` binding and `{{}}` in your html

```
  scope:{
    productId: '@'
  }
```

Your HTML:

```
<widget product-id="{{productId}}"></widget>
```

[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/a6jxVIiqIBEiGUH3iYXz?p=preview)